# Solace PubSub+ Software Message Broker AMI, how do we get updates?

Tags: amazon-ami, solace

I am running Solace PubSub+ Software Message Broker Standard Edition (AMI) in one AWS VPC. Recently I have deployed another instance in another AWS VPC and noticed that their version number is different.

1. May I know how do I upgrade/update the AMI in the original AWS VPC to the latest version?
2. If I need to redeploy the new AMI to the older VPC, is there a quick way for me to "save all the current settings including all the authentication certificates and push it to the new AMI?

Thank you.

Cheers~
Dylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For upgrading event broker on AWS, please follow instructions at https://docs.solace.com/Solace-SW-Broker-Upgrade/AWS-Upgrade.htm.

The event broker settings including the authentication certificates will be available to the new broker following the upgrading procedures.